# Change session object inside callback with express

Tags: mysql, node.js, session, express, authentication

I'm using express and mysql and I'm trying to finish my login feature.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
   var username = req.body.username;
   var password = sha1(req.body.password);
   db.query("SELECT user_id, username FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "';", function(err, rows, fields){
       if(rows.length > 0){
           console.log("User " + username + " connected.");
           req.session.user_id = rows[0].user_id;
      }
});
```

});

As you can see, I make a query on the database and if the username and password match, (rows.length >0) I try to log the user in by adding his id in the session object.

The problem is that the req.session is only modified inside the callback and I can't find a way to do it globally... I tried to call a function login(id) but that didn't work either.

A little help would be nice, thanks.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is the `express-session` module?

Comment: I had the module but I figured out a way to use it with global vars, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried passport but I think it was just too much to add to my application since I'm making something very small.
I figured out a way to change the session object after the callback by using app.locale which is a global variable then by destroying it right after.

EDIT : here's how I did it :

```
            if(rows.length > 0){

                // Put the user_id and its username on a global var
                app.locals.user_id = rows[0].user_id;
                app.locals.username = rows[0].username;
                res.redirect('/login');

                console.log("User " + username + " connected.".green);
            }
```

And when I have a POST request on /login

```
        if(app.locals.user_id){
            // Change the session object
            req.session.user_id = app.locals.user_id;
            req.session.username = app.locals.username;
    }
```

I guess there are better ways to do it but it works anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to authenticate users using a Mysql DB would be to add passport.js to the app.

See this repo for a full example : [Node-Express-Passport-Mysql authentication](https://github.com/manjeshpv/node-express-passport-mysql).

If you can't get it to work, let me know and I'll post a full code sample when I'm home.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll take a look tomorrow and let you know.